# Mode-dependent Andreev reflection

Tags: scattering, superconductivity

Consider the following Hamiltonian which describes massless Dirac fermion on the surface of a topological insulator nanowire,
$$H = -i\hbar v_{F}\left[ \partial_{x}\sigma_{x} + \frac{\sigma_{y}}{R}\left( \partial_{\phi} + i\eta\right)\right]\ \text{.}$$
The nanowire has translational symmetry in $x$-direction and $\phi$ is the angle around perimeter. It has eigenenergies which can be written in the form,
$$E_{k,n} = \pm \hbar v_{F} \sqrt{k^{2} + \frac{1}{R^2}\left(l_{n} + \eta \right)^2}\ \text{,}$$
where $l_{n} = n-1/2$ is quantized in integers $n$. The wavefunction can be written like this,
$$\Psi^{\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi L}}e^{\pm i k x}e^{i l_{n} \phi}\ \text{.}$$
Now, if You do the same thing but with the Bogoliubov-de Gennes equation You will get electron-like and hole-like solutions where the wavenumber $k$ woould depend on the total energy $\mathcal{E}$, transverse momentum $l_{n}$ and fraction of the magnetic flux quanta $\eta$.

I am wondering if the Andreev refelction at the boundary between normal-region and superconductor can take place between different modes $l_{n}$. Is there something which prevents from electron-electron, electron-hole etc. scattering processes between different modes at the N-S boundary?

Comment: This question requires clarification: we do not know what $\phi$ is actually. I think that, except for the impinging wave vector which gets reversed in the Andreev reflexion process, all other quantities are conserved by definition of a reflexion.